# Grails many to many relationship not creating expected tables

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, grails, grails-orm

Hi I have 2 domain classes. The idea is that a User can create events, as well as be a guest at other peoples events:

```
class Event {

Appuser creator
static belongsTo = Appuser
static hasMany = [guests: Appuser]
```

and

```
class Appuser {

    static hasMany = [friends: Appuser, events: Event]
```

The problem is, I expected it to make a `creator_id` column in the `event` table, and then an `appuser_events` table with just the `appuser_id` and the `event_id`, but it is also including a `creator_id` column here and making it the primary key.

I also tried creating my event class like this:

```
class Event {


    static belongsTo = [creator:Appuser]
    static hasMany = [guests: Appuser]
```

but then grails does not recognize the belongTo relationship.

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my issue. The key was to add 2 hasMany references to the Event class from Appuser, and then add a mappedBy, so my Event Class now contains:

```
static hasMany = [friends: Appuser, events: Event, invites:Event]
static mappedBy = [invites: "guests", events: "creator"]
```

The Appuser class is unchanged from my first example in the question.